# Minimum drum wall thickness when rope wrapped around it

Tags: mechanical-engineering, wire, crushing

I need to design a hollow drum that holds steel wire rope under tension. The wire rope gets pulled from both ends with a force of 200kN, it is wrapped around the drum 5 times. The outer diameter needs to be 1m and I was thinking of using S355 for this application.

My question is: How would I go about calculating the minimum wall thickness of the drum, as to withstand the ''crushing'' pressure of the wire wrapped around it?

Answer (score 1):

if you cut the drum longitudinally into two half-cylinders you will have 10 cut ropes with a tension of 200kN.

Let's say the center to center distance of each rope is L inches (moderately small WRT. to the radius) then you have to calculate the area of the section of the barrel between the ropes and a thickness,t, and a safety factor of 1.6

$$1.6*200kN/(L*t)< \sigma y_{steel}$$

$$ t> 1.6 \frac{200kN}{L \sigma y_{steel}} $$

Comment: You also need to consider bucking of the drum, which is complicated (and knowing only the diameter is not enough data). See https://www.abbottaerospace.com/aa-sb-001/15-local-stability-isotropic-materials/15-4-buckling-specific-cases/15-4-1-buckling-of-thin-cylindrical-shells/ for example.

Comment: @alephzero, i treated this loosely as a barrel under external uniform pressure. It is handled in the industry the same. of course, the assumption is spotty. But is a good approximation.

Comment: I agree there is nothing wrong with the approximation as a static analysis. On the other hand buckling failures are like walking around near the edge of a cliff wearing a blindfold. Either you fall over the edge or you don't. You don't get any warning signs (like excessive bending or permanent plastic deformation) before it happens!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest checking hoop stress due to torsion against the allowable shear stress of the drum as graphically shown below. It should be a multi steps process - 1) Assume line element with thickness t and diameter d ≈ D, then solving for t. 2) From the obtained t, solve d, then check the stress again. 3) Adjust t and repeat step 2 if necessary.
[image]

[image]

[image]